# How to use three buttons as like segment control

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

[image]Hi may anyone let me know how to use three buttons to use like segment control in iPhone.

Comment: just out of curiosity why can't you use a segment control if you want to use buttons like segment control..?

Comment: see the above pic..I want to do like that when i was trying to do this possible with segment control but when we click on white color gaps then also action will be happen..but that should not cause any action  OK..

Comment: colour can be an issue - sometimes you can only use the default blue. I also had a design given to me once that had different width of buttons (yuck) but they insisted they wanted it so I had to implement the control as buttons :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set tag on each button.

```
[button1 setTag:0];
[button2 setTag:1];
[button3 setTag:2];
```

Then put the same @selector method for all buttons.

Then in your button selector method do this:-

```
 -(IBAction)youButtonMethod:(id)sender
{
    if([sender tag] == 0)
    {
       // your first button click
    }

    else if([sender tag] == 1)
    {
       // your second button click
    }

    else if([sender tag] == 2)
    {
       // your third button click
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Place three buttons with different tags and connect all three with a single IBAction and then make use of switch case flow to do whatever on basis of tags

```
 -(IBAction)segmentControleChanged:(id)sender
 {

  switch([sender tag]){

      case 1:
      {
        //Do anyting
        break;
      }

      case 2:
      {
         //Do anyting
         break;
      }

      case 3:
     {
        //Do anyting
        break;
      }


      default:
      break;
    }

}
```

supposing that you have 3 buttons with tag 1 , 2 ,3

Comment: why not add all UIButtons to an array and use the default ´@selector´? simply send the UIButton.selected as YES to the selected one.